# Modifying SimpleCursorAdapter's data

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter, android-viewbinder

I'm working on a TV Guide app which uses a `ListActivity` showing the TV shows for one channel / one day at a time. I'm using a `RelativeLayout` for the `ListView` items and I want the `ListView` to look something like this:

```
07:00 The Breakfast Show
      Latest news and topical reports
08:00 Tom and Jerry
      More cat and mouse capers
```

I get the data for the `ListView` items using the following code:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SELECT blah,blah,blah);
String[] columnNames = new String[]{"start_time","title", "subtitle"};
int[] resIds = new int[]{R.id.start_time_short, R.id.title, R.id.subtitle};
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.guide_list_item, cursor, columnNames, resIds);
```

My problem is that the `start_time` field is a `datetime` with the following format:

```
2011-01-23 07:00:00
```

so what I get is this:

```
2011-01-23 07:00:00 The Breakfast Show
                    Latest news and topical reports
2011-01-23 08:00:00 Tom and Jerry
                    More cat and mouse capers
```

What I'd like to do is format the above using `SimpleDateFormat`(`"HH:mm"`) so I only get the `hour:minute` part of the `start_time` field.

I've found the `SimpleCursor.ViewBinder` interface which suggests it may be what I want but I can't figure out how to use it. If I'm right about `ViewBinder`, I'd appreciate some pointers to sample code on how to use it. Otherwise, how else can I achieve changing the `start_time` field to simply show `HH:mm` format?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int column) {
        if( column == 0 ){ // let's suppose that the column 0 is the date
            TextView tv = (TextView) view;
            String dateStr = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name_of_the_date_column"));
            // here you use SimpleDateFormat to bla blah blah
            tv.setText(theFormatedDate);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that explains it very well. I re-worked your example to fit my code and it's working perfectly for me.

Comment: This just saved my butt trying to re-order the row counts from a Cursor, so thank you sir.   My code is as follows:

HistoryAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
   @Override
   public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int column) {
    if (column == 0) { // let's suppose that the column 0 is the
         // date

     TextView tv = (TextView) view;
     String rownum = String.valueOf(cursor.getPosition() + 1);
     // here you use SimpleDateFormat to bla blah blah
     tv.setText(rownum);

     return true;
    }
    return false;
   }
  });

Comment: @Cristian Please, do you think you could help with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27257416/android-how-can-i-pass-data-related-to-two-tables-to-a-the-insert-method-of-a?